# How can I show a background image with its associated title

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

I have a question regarding how I might display a number of different background images on my site (not a slideshow but page specific backgrounds) along with an image title/credit line of text specific to each image?

I can position the text ok but not sure how to change the text with each new image.

This is what I have so far:

```css
#header #headerbanner {
  float: right;
  width: 468px;
  margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background: font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#header #headerbanner h3 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans 
 Unicode",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;

}

#header #headerbanner p a {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #a8ef9d;
}

#header #headerbanner a:hover {
  background: url(images/blacktrans.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="headerbanner" class="widget widget_block widget_text">
  <p>Image: Eildon Hills, Scottish Borders</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

S

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Please add the code you have done so far

Comment: Done Abin. As you will no doubt see, I am a designer not a coder!

Comment: Your CSS uses a fixed background image (i.e. the background image does not change based on time or page reload). So it's totally fine to have the text fixed as well.
If your page should have different background when the user reloads or based on time, then some code is needed to change the image and the text.  Both would be done in a similar manner.  
Reach out to your coder for some help on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some JavaScript to always move to the next image/text:

```
setInterval(nextImage, 10000);

function nextImage() {
  // Repeats every 5 seconds
}
```

Before this function just select the image and text element by using IDs and the JavaScript getElementById function.

```
<p id="text"></p>
<img id="img"></img>
text = document.getElementById('text');
img = document.getElementById('img');
```

And in this function set content of these elements

```
text.innerHTML = "Your Authors Name";
img.style.background = "url(newUrl/)";
```

In the function you should also use an Array with all names and images. And an counter and

```
if(counter>=imgArray.length) {
   counter=0;
} else {
   counter++;
}
```

And use the counter to display the text and image on the current position.

Comment: Sounds like a great answer Jorit. Where would I apply this code? Also, I need the image / text to change on navigating to a new page if that is possible?

Comment: I could help you the best if you setup your project on https://jsfiddle.net so I can take a look and make changes with comments :)

Comment: Hy Jorit here is the link to jsfiddle.net : https://jsfiddle.net/soutra/L8zp3ktf/1/#&togetherjs=75Uy59qq7b

Comment: I don't have access to the html as it is a wordpress theme.